# Mark profiles I don't want to contact on Careers 2.0

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

As an employer using Careers 2.0 profile search, I found it very useful. While I could mark and save profiles for the 'yes' profiles, I kept running into folks that I had previously mentally tagged as not a fit. I had to rely on paper, memory, or simply clicking the profile again and remembering why I had not contacted those people.

It would be useful to have a way to mark profiles as 'not a fit' or something to keep me from redundantly reviewing profiles.

Comment: Hang on tight.  We're just working out the kinks.

Answer (score 3):

This was implemented last year as part of our candidate manager release.  There is now a button to dismiss profiles directly from search.  By default we only hide dismissed candidates from further searches for the same position, however you can also opt to filter dismissed profiles from all searches using the advanced search feature.